# How to choose right and good notation and symbols?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

I learn group theory for research purpose. From last few time I am struggling to come with good notation and right symbols. Is there any good way to learn how to use best symbols.

> For example suppose $g \in C_g$ is a right symbol or $x \in C_g$ is a good notation. Now suppose I have to show a group is normal in $G$ then should I use $xHx^{-1} =H$ or $gHg^{-1}$ which is better. Same question I have for generating set.

Question :  How to choose right and good notation and symbols for research writing?

Comment: 1. Look up what symbols people in your field tend you use. If you use the notations that most people are familiar with, they will understand your writing more easily. 2. Strongly avoid using the same symbol or very similar ones for different things. 3. Only invent your own notation if that is really unavoidable.

Comment: It is advisable to check what notation is used in your particular field. Often notation slightly differs between mathematical disciplines. What is most important, however, is that you explain your notation to your reader if it is not clear or if it differs a lot from conventional notation in your field of research. Lastly, all the notation, symbols and names we use are only conventions but they are not carved in stone. Nobody could hinder you if you called what is commonly referred to as *group* Peter instead or assign any other name to it.

Comment: If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, I always find it easy if the elements of the group are denoted by lower case letters. Like $g \in G$ or $h \in H$. This is more comfortable to read, rather than choosing $x \in G$ or $x \in H$ as one has to keep a track of it.

Comment: You might want to choose the notation that makes it easier for you to work. At least, that's what I normally do. For instance, I built my most recent papers on some excellent articles by some other authors. But I was only able to made progress after translating in my preferred notation what they had written.

Answer (score 2):

Two pieces of advice based on your examples:

- It often helps to use the same sort of letters for the same sort of things to speed up comprehension. e.g. $m$ and $n$ are always natural number or at least integers; $i$, $j$ and $k$ are indices. For groups, you usually see $g$ and then $h$ as group elements, which is why I slightly prefer $gHg^{-1}$ over $xHx^{-1}$.
- Always be aware of when you are using the same symbols for things. $g \in C_g$ means something entirely different to $x \in C_g$. The first is a summary of the proof that $g(g)g^{-1}=g$ and therefore $g$ must be in its own centraliser. The second just picks some element $x$ in the centraliser of g. If you write as though those notations mean the same thing you are going to confuse your reader.